# web audio numberOfInputs is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I don't know if the problem is that I don't understand the definition of `numberOfInputs` but when I run this code

```
var cx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var g = cx.createGain();
g.connect(cx.destination);
console.log("numberOfInputs:"+g.numberOfInputs);
```

console says `numberOfInputs:1` but there is nothing connected to `g`
Then I change and run this code

```
var cx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var g = cx.createGain();
g.connect(cx.destination);

var o1 = cx.createOscillator();
o1.frequency.setValueAtTime(200, cx.currentTime);
o1.connect(g);
o1.start();

var o2 = cx.createOscillator();
o2.frequency.setValueAtTime(500, cx.currentTime);
o2.connect(g);
o2.start();

console.log("numberOfInputs:"+g.numberOfInputs);
```

console says `numberOfInputs:1` and it should be 2
firefox,edge,chrome output the same value
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `g` returned by `createGain` is a [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) where you will find detail explanation.

> A GainNode always has exactly one input and one output, ...